# How to insert multiple values to database

Tags: postgresql, go

In my Go application I have such **route**:

```
router.HandleFunc("/api/users_groups_relationship/{user_id:[0-9]+}", controllers.CreateUsersGroupsRelationship).Methods("POST")
```

I make **POST** request. In body of that request I send such JSON which looks like this:

```
{
    "groups": [1, 2, 3] 
}
```

As you can see `groups` key has array of ids as value. User can be in several groups. I am trying to insert multiple values to PostgreSQL database.

1. How to get the value of a specific key in request body?
2. Is there any other best way to insert multiple values in database by Go?

My code:

```
var CreateUsersGroupsRelationship  = func(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(request)

    userID := vars["user_id"]

    fmt.Println(userID)

    var groups []int

    groups = request.Body("groups") // ???

    for i := 1; i < len(groups); i++ {
        fmt.Println(groups[i])
        _, _ := database.DBSQL.Exec("INSERT INTO users_groups (user_id, group_id) VALUES ($1, $2);", userID, groups[i])
    }

    utils.ResponseWithSuccess(responseWriter, http.StatusOK, "All new records successfully created.")
}
```

Comment: What's the Content-type of body? is it json?

Comment: Yes, your are right. `Content-Type` is `application/json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a struct for Request object and then unmarshal JSON into it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "net/http"
    "encoding/json"
)

//Request is our request body.
type Request struct {
    Groups []int `json:"groups"`
}

//JsonTest1 is the http handler.
func JsonTest1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    req := new(Request)
    //decode request to struct.
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&req); err != nil{
        w.WriteHeader(400) //bad request
    }

    w.WriteHeader(200)
    b, _ := json.Marshal(req)
    w.Write(b)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
}

func main(){
    fmt.Printf("starting backend server\n")

    root := mux.NewRouter()
    root.HandleFunc("/foo", JsonTest1)

    webServer := &http.Server{Addr: ":4000", Handler: root}

    webServer.ListenAndServe()
}
```

In case your body is quite generic, you can also unmarshal to map[string]interface{}.

Try with

```
curl -XPOST -d '{"groups": [1]}' http://localhost:4000/foo
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code right now. `fmt.Println(req.Groups)` return empty array. Do you have any ideas why it happens?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek can you paste your request body here?
the above code will work for body:
{"groups": [1]}

Comment: Finally I notice that it's my mistake. In JSON body I make typo. Thank you for your help! How do your think is this best idea to insert data one by one to database as I am trying to make?

Comment: you should batch insert rather if your db provides it.
for example in postgres i could do:
INSERT INTO user_group (id, group_id) VALUES
    (1,1),
    (1,2);

Comment: I also thought about it but as you can see array in JSON body always contains different number of elements. For thats why SQL statement must be dynamic. So how I need to change my code inside loop to make such dynamic SQL as you adviced? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek check this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486436/golang-how-do-i-batch-sql-statements-with-package-database-sql/25192138#25192138